# LiveData object Observer never gets called

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have an Activity that has a fragment with a viewmodel in it. The Activity needs to be able to update the livedata object's value as well as does the fragment.

I declared my ViewModel for the fragment like this:

```
class BottomNavViewModel:ViewModel() {
    var isConnected = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
}
```

In the BottomNavFragment I have this code to declare the ViewModel

```
    private val viewModel: BottomNavViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BottomNavViewModel::class.java) }
```

A few lines below that I have this:

```
private val changeObserver = Observer<Boolean> { value ->
    value?.let {
        Timber.i("Update of isConnected received. Updating text field now")

        if(it) {
            connectedText.text = getString(R.string.connected)
            connectedText.setTextColor(activity!!.getColor(R.color.colorSelectedGreen))
        }
        else {
            connectedText.text = getString(R.string.not_connected)
            connectedText.setTextColor(activity!!.getColor(R.color.off_red))
        }
    }

    ...

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is BottomNavFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        listener = context
    }
    else {
        throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
    }

    viewModel.isConnected.observe(this, changeObserver)
}
```

That Observer never, ever, gets hit.

In my Activity I have this:

```
    private var sharedBottomNavViewModel:BottomNavViewModel? = null

    ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection)

    sharedBottomNavViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BottomNavViewModel::class.java)

    ...
    override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    startBackgroundThread()
    checkCameraPermission()

    //TODO: Change this to listen for a connection
    sharedBottomNavViewModel?.let {
        Timber.i("Updating isConnected to true now")
        it.isConnected.value = true
    }
}
```

In the logs I see the messages indicating that the update occurs but the observer never gets the message.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here please?

Answer (score 1):

Your 2 viewmodels are not the same. You are creating a viewmodel and passing the lifecycle owner, and in one case you specify the fragment, and in the other the activity.

Change your fragment like this:

```
private val viewModel: BottomNavViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(BottomNavViewModel::class.java) }
```

Be careful where you initialize the viewmodel though, as `activity` (`getActivity()`) is `nullable`.

Edit: (credit Ian Lake) Or, if you use the `fragment-ktx` artifacts, you can do this

```
private val viewModel: BottomNavViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Comment: Note that the version 1.1.0 of `fragment-ktx` artifact allows you to write `private val viewModel: BottomNavViewModel by activityViewModels()` to get the same functionality.

Comment: That was it! Thanks